# Access Azure blob storage from R notebook

Tags: r, azure, azure-storage, sparkr

in python this is how I would access a csv from Azure blobs

```
storage_account_name = "testname"
storage_account_access_key = "..."
file_location = "wasb://example@testname.blob.core.windows.net/testfile.csv"

spark.conf.set(
  "fs.azure.account.key."+storage_account_name+".blob.core.windows.net",
  storage_account_access_key)

df = spark.read.format('csv').load(file_location, header = True, inferSchema = True)
```

How can I do this in R? I cannot find any documentation...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [AzureStor](https://cran.r-project.org/package=AzureStor) package provides an R interface to Azure storage, including files, blobs and ADLSgen2.

```
endp <- storage_endpoint("https://acctname.blob.core.windows.net", key="access_key")
cont <- storage_container(endp, "mycontainer")
storage_download(cont, "myblob.csv", "local_filename.csv")
```

Note that this will download to a file in local storage. From there, you can ingest into Spark using standard Sparklyr methods.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of AzureStor.

Comment: is there a way to access the blob/file on Azure directly, as a data table (for example), without downloading the file first?

Comment: @Hong Ooi, could you please tell if we could get the stored access policy for a blob via `azurestor` package ?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to download it, create a tempfile and then read from it

```
   endp <- storage_endpoint("https://acctname.blob.core.windows.net", key="access_key")
   cont <- storage_container(endp, "mycontainer")
   fname <- tempfile()
   storage_download(cont, "myblob.csv", fname)
   df = read.csv(fname)
```