# Read Azure Blob/File into a R data table without downloading the file

Tags: r, azure, data.table

As a follow-up to the question here [Access Azure blob storage from R notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54851723/access-azure-blob-storage-from-r-notebook)

Is there a way to access the blob/file on Azure directly, as a data table (for example), without downloading the file first?

Below code first downloads the file in my directory, creating redundancy.

````
endp <- storage_endpoint("https://acctname.blob.core.windows.net", key="access_key")
cont <- storage_container(endp, "mycontainer")
storage_download(cont, "myblob.csv", "local_filename.csv")```
````

Comment: Check this.https://github.com/Azure/AzureStor#transfer-to-and-from-connections