# Accessing files from Azure blob storage by logging in/authenticating interactively

Tags: r, azure

How do I access files from Azure blob storage by logging in/authenticating interactively i.e without using a token or key?

For example, with the DBI package one can access an Azure SQL db as follows:

```
con <- dbConnect(odbc(),
                 UID = "username" 
                 Driver = "SQL Server", 
                 Server = "server URL", 
                 Database = "databasename", 
                 Authentication = "ActiveDirectoryInterractive")
```

Is there something similar with blob storage?

I have tried functions from AzureR but haven't been successful so far.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> used this [Access Azure blob storage from R notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54851723/access-azure-blob-storage-from-r-notebook)  So link @Hong Ooi

```r
 fname <- tempfile()
   storage_download(cont, "myblob.csv", fname)
   df = read.csv(fname)
```

**Output:**
[image]

- For  R interface to Azure storage accounts Azure Active Directory  Refer this [link](https://github.com/Azure/AzureStor)